# Using ncu to profile pagefault in unified memory

Tags: cuda, nsight-compute

is there any option to profile unified virtual memory CUDA application with Nsight Compute (NCU)? For example, I want to know the time spending on handling page fault and migration.

Comment: you would typically use nsight systems for this not nsight compute

Comment: Hi, when I use the command like `nsys profile --stats=true --cuda-um-gpu-page-faults=true --cuda-um-cpu-page-faults=true  ./myapplication` it does not showup any profiling statistics about those page faulting in the output, there any step I was missing? @RobertCrovella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the solution by myself. Just need to specify `--export=json` to output the profiling result into json file to get the detailed metrics of page fault.
The overall profiling command looks like this.

```
nsys profile \
     --force-overwrite=true \
     --cuda-um-gpu-page-faults=true \
     --cuda-um-cpu-page-faults=true \
     --export=json \
     ./yourapplication
```